# Estimating Right Censored Data

Tags: poisson-distribution, count-data, censoring, weibull-distribution, tobit-regression

I'm a newbie at Math, and I am just getting my feet wet when it comes to understanding math and statistics so please forgive my ignorance or question if it's already been answered or if materials are already readily available.

I have a few friends who I'm counting how many steps it takes them to complete a puzzle. They have to complete a variety of different puzzles. They are free to stop at any point so some friends have more or less observations than other friends. I only give my friends 7 tries to complete the puzzle after which I don't know how long it would've theoretically taken them to complete the puzzle.

Relevant points:

1. This is count data in which 0 is not a possible value.
2. My data is right censored at the value of 7.

Data generally looks like:

Friend 1: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]
Friend 2: [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7]

I am curious about how I would go about estimating what my friend's who didn't the complete puzzle's values would be had I allowed them to keep trying to guess the puzzle. The purpose is to estimate those values for generating an average and determining which friend was the best at solving the puzzles.

Solutions in R and Python would be preferred. I've been looking in tobit models, censored Poisson, and survival analysis using the Weibull distribution, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is actually correct since at this point I'm just googling around and throwing stuff at the wall to see what works. I'm having a little trouble understanding the Math as well at this point as well which is why I'm not sure which modelling procedure would be best (or how to even determine which modelling procedure would be best).

Comment: I have a situation with censored data that is similar to yours. Curious if there is an existing solution which is appropriate for modeling the data in this setup.